# Can a table have columns that are not dependent on primary key, and still be in 2NF?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling, database-normalization

I am new to databases and have been learning about the normal forms / database practices over the past two days. I have created the following mock-up table for aircraft inspection data, but I am not sure if it is in the second normal form. Inspection ID is the primary key, but the only info that is really dependent on the Inspection ID is the Date. Technical Order is a guideline that a mechanic follows for an aircraft inspection, but it doesn't affect the Inspection ID in any way. Inspector Name is also not dependent on Inspection ID.

Would this table break 2NF if two columns are not dependent on the primary key?

The table is below:

[image]

Comment: NFs use FDs. But you don't say what you think they are. NFs use CKs, not PKs. 2NF involves partial & full FDs, but you don't mention them. Also why do you think "if two columns are not dependent on the primary key" has anything to do with 2NF? Why are you thinking about it? Show your work following your texbook & ask a specific question about the first place you are stuck. PS If you do that you might see that the currently accepted answer is wrong & confused.

Comment: PS "the only info that is really dependent on the Inspection ID is the Date" doesn't make sense since every column is functionally dependent on every CK/PK. "affect the Inspection ID in any way" doesn't make sense since FDs have nothing to do with "affecting".  (Whatever "really" & "in any way" mean.) This post doesn't show understanding of the terms used. This exemplifies why you should show the steps & justification of your work following a textbook--or we can't tell you where you went right & wrong or sometimes even make sense of writing (if it makes sense). Google 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Except this isn't a textbook. I actually do have to implement a database for my work. I don't have any previous experience with databases, so i am trying to get a clear grasp on things so that i don't end up implementing a badly-designed database.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether this is homework or your job, given that you posted this question, you need to read a textbook. The question is lacking so much understanding that answering it or explaining the things wrong with your question requires explaining from scratch. That's too broad for SO. Look: 2NF is useless! Nevertheless, 2NF means a particular thing, involving FDs & CKs & not PKs. If you got textbook/correct definitions then you'd see that you need to first identify FDs. Start there. Post a question doing that. Give all steps with justification & ask about where you are first stuck.

Comment: Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online DB course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has a primary key that is a single column and no other unique keys (or so it looks), so it is automatically in second normal form, because there is no (non-empty) *proper subset* of the primary key.

The rest of my answer deals with the question whether the table satisfies the *third normal form* or not (thanks for pointing that out, philipxy).

---

There does not have to be any logical dependency between the primary key and the data. In fact, primary keys are often artificially generated numbers.

The point is that no field should depend on any field *other than* the primary key.

For example, if the `Inspector Name` in your example would always be the same for a `Technical Order`, the table would *not* be in second normal form. In that case, you would create a second table where `Technical Order` is the primary key and `Inspector Name` would be a field. Your original table would then only contain `Technical Order` as a *foreign key* to that second table.

Normalizing your data model in this way avoids redundancy, which reduces storage space and automatically reduces the danger of inconsistency (now it cannot happen that there are two rows with the same `Technical Order`, but a different `Inspector Name`.

To tell if a table is normalized or not, you have to know the semantics of the data.

Comment: "no field should depend on any field other than the primary key" is wrong. See a definition of 2NF.

Comment: You are right, I was talking about 3NF. I tried to fix the answer.

Comment: It's wrong re 3NF & still 2NF too. Your statements are not reflecting the details of the meanings/definitions. See a definition of 3NF. Eg primeness matters. Eg you say unique keys (superkey) but you presumably mean CKs. Eg you are repeating the  common misconception that all CKs simple implies 2NF. (Also necessary is, {} must also not determine a column.) But the question is too vague to do anything with anyway. In summary, all you have to do to see these problems is follow my comment on the question & try justify your claims by reference to a (good) academic textbook.

Comment: Imagining a non-composite key where something depends on part of it is conceivable, but not very realistic. My aim was to translate the definitions into language that is familiar to database practitioners, at the risk of losing precision. After all, normalization has practical value. It is pretty obvious to me that `inspection_id` is the only key of any description of a table of inspections, so while my sloppy answer certainly glosses over the distinctions, it should not be wrong. This is hardly the place to develop rigorous definitions, and I had the impression they were not asked for.

Comment: But I really appreciate your comments, they made me re-read the definitions that, as you probably guessed, were not fresh in my mind after all the years since my academic training.

Comment: Thanks. My take on your answer & your comments on it & your approach is that your writing when high-level is mostly unclear & when low-level is often wrong or only correct given unstated assumptions & is always lacking justification, which doesn't help the asker with this or any other example. PS 1. {}->X iff all rows have the same X value. Uncommon, but easily conceived. But you miss the point: I used such FDs to disprove your "automatically 2NF" by counterexample. 2. The question *is* trying to be precise. Even towards FDs that hold & don't hold. But it holds misconceptions & is unclear.